# jQuery Scroll not working. (Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined )

Tags: javascript, jquery, opencart

I have installed a theme on opencart 1.5.6.4 and for some reason the scroll carousel doesn't work. I have included the file below. Can anyone see any errors? Or also look at the website on chrome web inspector.

The error on google chrome web inspector says

> Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined

But I am not very good with javascript so I don't know what the error could be.

http://ilovefancydress.com/

[Link to js file](http://ilovefancydress.com/catalog/view/theme/madame/js/jquery.jcarousel.min.js)

```
(function(t) {
    "use strict";
    var i = t.jCarousel = {};
    i.version = "0.3.0-beta.5";
    var s = /^([+\-]=)?(.+)$/;
    i.parseTarget = function(t) {
        var i = !1,
            e = "object" != typeof t ? s.exec(t) : null;
        return e ? (t = parseInt(e[2], 10) || 0, e[1] && (i = !0, "-=" ===
            e[1] && (t *= -1))) : "object" != typeof t && (t =
            parseInt(t, 10) || 0), {
            target: t,
            relative: i
        }
    }, i.detectCarousel = function(t) {
        for (var i; t.size() > 0;) {
            if (i = t.filter("[data-jcarousel]"), i.size() > 0) return i;
            if (i = t.find("[data-jcarousel]"), i.size() > 0) return i;
            t = t.parent()
        }
        return null
    }, i.base = function(s) {
        return {
            version: i.version,
            _options: {},
            _element: null,
            _carousel: null,
            _init: t.noop,
            _create: t.noop,
            _destroy: t.noop,
            _reload: t.noop,
            create: function() {
                return this._element.attr("data-" + s.toLowerCase(), !
                    0).data(s, this), !1 === this._trigger(
                    "create") ? this : (this._create(), this._trigger(
                    "createend"), this)
            },
            destroy: function() {
                return !1 === this._trigger("destroy") ? this : (
                    this._destroy(), this._trigger("destroyend"),
                    this._element.removeData(s).removeAttr(
                        "data-" + s.toLowerCase()), this)
            },
            reload: function(t) {
                return !1 === this._trigger("reload") ? this : (t &&
                    this.options(t), this._reload(), this._trigger(
                        "reloadend"), this)
            },
            element: function() {
                return this._element
            },
            options: function(i, s) {
                if (0 === arguments.length) return t.extend({},
                    this._options);
                if ("string" == typeof i) {
                    if (s === void 0) return this._options[i] ===
                        void 0 ? null : this._options[i];
                    this._options[i] = s
                } else this._options = t.extend({}, this._options,
                    i);
                return this
            },
            carousel: function() {
                return this._carousel || (this._carousel = i.detectCarousel(
                    this.options("carousel") || this._element
                ), this._carousel || t.error(
                    'Could not detect carousel for plugin "' +
                    s + '"')), this._carousel
            },
            _trigger: function(i, e, r) {
                var n, o = !1;
                return r = [this].concat(r || []), (e || this._element)
                    .each(function() {
                        n = t.Event((i + "." + s).toLowerCase()),
                            t(this).trigger(n, r), n.isDefaultPrevented() &&
                            (o = !0)
                    }), !o
            }
        }
    }, i.plugin = function(s, e) {
        var r = t[s] = function(i, s) {
            this._element = t(i), this.options(s), this._init(),
                this.create()
        };
        return r.fn = r.prototype = t.extend({}, i.base(s), e), t.fn[s] =
            function(i) {
                var e = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1),
                    n = this;
                return "string" == typeof i ? this.each(function() {
                    var r = t(this).data(s);
                    if (!r) return t.error(
                        "Cannot call methods on " + s +
                        " prior to initialization; " +
                        'attempted to call method "' +
                        i + '"');
                    if (!t.isFunction(r[i]) || "_" === i.charAt(
                        0)) return t.error('No such method "' +
                        i + '" for ' + s + " instance");
                    var o = r[i].apply(r, e);
                    return o !== r && o !== void 0 ? (n = o, !1) :
                        void 0
                }) : this.each(function() {
                    var e = t(this).data(s);
                    e instanceof r ? e.reload(i) : new r(this,
                        i)
                }), n
            }, r
    }
})(jQuery),
function(t, i) {
    "use strict";
    var s = function(t) {
        return parseFloat(t) || 0
    };
    t.jCarousel.plugin("jcarousel", {
        animating: !1,
        tail: 0,
        inTail: !1,
        resizeTimer: null,
        lt: null,
        vertical: !1,
        rtl: !1,
        circular: !1,
        underflow: !1,
        _options: {
            list: function() {
                return this.element().children().eq(0)
            },
            items: function() {
                return this.list().children()
            },
            animation: 400,
            transitions: !1,
            wrap: null,
            vertical: null,
            rtl: null,
            center: !1
        },
        _list: null,
        _items: null,
        _target: null,
        _first: null,
        _last: null,
        _visible: null,
        _fullyvisible: null,
        _init: function() {
            var t = this;
            return this.onWindowResize = function() {
                t.resizeTimer && clearTimeout(t.resizeTimer), t
                    .resizeTimer = setTimeout(function() {
                        t.reload()
                    }, 100)
            }, this
        },
        _create: function() {
            this._reload(), t(i).on("resize.jcarousel", this.onWindowResize)
        },
        _destroy: function() {
            t(i).off("resize.jcarousel", this.onWindowResize)
        },
        _reload: function() {
            this.vertical = this.options("vertical"), null == this.vertical &&
                (this.vertical = this.list().height() > this.list()
                    .width()), this.rtl = this.options("rtl"), null ==
                this.rtl && (this.rtl = function(i) {
                    if ("rtl" === ("" + i.attr("dir")).toLowerCase())
                        return !0;
                    var s = !1;
                    return i.parents("[dir]").each(function() {
                        return /rtl/i.test(t(this).attr(
                                "dir")) ? (s = !0, !1) :
                            void 0
                    }), s
                }(this._element)), this.lt = this.vertical ? "top" :
                "left", this._items = null;
            var i = this._target && this.index(this._target) >= 0 ?
                this._target : this.closest();
            this.circular = "circular" === this.options("wrap"),
                this.underflow = !1;
            var s = {
                left: 0,
                top: 0
            };
            return i.size() > 0 && (this._prepare(i), this.list().find(
                    "[data-jcarousel-clone]").remove(), this._items =
                null, this.underflow = this._fullyvisible.size() >=
                this.items().size(), this.circular = this.circular &&
                !this.underflow, s[this.lt] = this._position(i) +
                "px"), this.move(s), this
        },
        list: function() {
            if (null === this._list) {
                var i = this.options("list");
                this._list = t.isFunction(i) ? i.call(this) : this._element
                    .find(i)
            }
            return this._list
        },
        items: function() {
            if (null === this._items) {
                var i = this.options("items");
                this._items = (t.isFunction(i) ? i.call(this) :
                    this.list().find(i)).not(
                    "[data-jcarousel-clone]")
            }
            return this._items
        },
        index: function(t) {
            return this.items().index(t)
        },
        closest: function() {
            var i, e = this,
                r = this.list().position()[this.lt],
                n = t(),
                o = !1,
                a = this.vertical ? "bottom" : this.rtl ? "left" :
                "right";
            return this.rtl && !this.vertical && (r = -1 * (r +
                    this.list().width() - this.clipping())), this.items()
                .each(function() {
                    if (n = t(this), o) return !1;
                    var l = e.dimension(n);
                    if (r += l, r >= 0) {
                        if (i = l - s(n.css("margin-" + a)), !(
                            0 >= Math.abs(r) - l + i / 2))
                            return !1;
                        o = !0
                    }
                }), n
        },
        target: function() {
            return this._target
        },
        first: function() {
            return this._first
        },
        last: function() {
            return this._last
        },
        visible: function() {
            return this._visible
        },
        fullyvisible: function() {
            return this._fullyvisible
        },
        hasNext: function() {
            if (!1 === this._trigger("hasnext")) return !0;
            var t = this.options("wrap"),
                i = this.items().size() - 1;
            return i >= 0 && (t && "first" !== t || i > this.index(
                    this._last) || this.tail && !this.inTail) ? !0 :
                !1
        },
        hasPrev: function() {
            if (!1 === this._trigger("hasprev")) return !0;
            var t = this.options("wrap");
            return this.items().size() > 0 && (t && "last" !== t ||
                this.index(this._first) > 0 || this.tail &&
                this.inTail) ? !0 : !1
        },
        clipping: function() {
            return this._element["inner" + (this.vertical ?
                "Height" : "Width")]()
        },
        dimension: function(t) {
            return t["outer" + (this.vertical ? "Height" : "Width")]
                (!0)
        },
        scroll: function(i, e, r) {
            if (this.animating) return this;
            if (!1 === this._trigger("scroll", null, [i, e])) return
                this;
            t.isFunction(e) && (r = e, e = !0);
            var n = t.jCarousel.parseTarget(i);
            if (n.relative) {
                var o, a, l, h, u, c, f, d, _ = this.items().size() -
                    1,
                    p = Math.abs(n.target),
                    m = this.options("wrap");
                if (n.target > 0) {
                    var v = this.index(this._last);
                    if (v >= _ && this.tail) this.inTail ? "both" ===
                        m || "last" === m ? this._scroll(0, e, r) :
                        this._scroll(Math.min(this.index(this._target) +
                            p, _), e, r) : this._scrollTail(e, r);
                    else if (o = this.index(this._target), this.underflow &&
                        o === _ && ("circular" === m || "both" ===
                            m || "last" === m) || !this.underflow &&
                        v === _ && ("both" === m || "last" === m))
                        this._scroll(0, e, r);
                    else if (l = o + p, this.circular && l > _) {
                        for (d = _, u = this.items().get(-1); l > d++;)
                            u = this.items().eq(0), c = this._visible
                            .index(u) >= 0, c && u.after(u.clone(!0)
                                .attr("data-jcarousel-clone", !0)),
                            this.list().append(u), c || (f = {}, f[
                                    this.lt] = this.dimension(u) *
                                (this.rtl ? -1 : 1), this.moveBy(f)
                            ), this._items = null;
                        this._scroll(u, e, r)
                    } else this._scroll(Math.min(l, _), e, r)
                } else if (this.inTail) this._scroll(Math.max(this.index(
                    this._first) - p + 1, 0), e, r);
                else if (a = this.index(this._first), o = this.index(
                        this._target), h = this.underflow ? o : a,
                    l = h - p, 0 >= h && (this.underflow &&
                        "circular" === m || "both" === m || "first" ===
                        m)) this._scroll(_, e, r);
                else if (this.circular && 0 > l) {
                    for (d = l, u = this.items().get(0); 0 > d++;) {
                        u = this.items().eq(-1), c = this._visible.index(
                                u) >= 0, c && u.after(u.clone(!0).attr(
                                "data-jcarousel-clone", !0)), this.list()
                            .prepend(u), this._items = null;
                        var g = s(this.list().position()[this.lt]),
                            y = this.dimension(u);
                        this.rtl && !this.vertical ? g += y : g -=
                            y, f = {}, f[this.lt] = g + "px", this.move(
                                f)
                    }
                    this._scroll(u, e, r)
                } else this._scroll(Math.max(l, 0), e, r)
            } else this._scroll(n.target, e, r);
            return this._trigger("scrollend"), this
        },
        moveBy: function(t, i) {
            var e = this.list().position();
            return t.left && (t.left = e.left + s(t.left) + "px"),
                t.top && (t.top = e.top + s(t.top) + "px"), this.move(
                    t, i)
        },
        move: function(i, s) {
            s = s || {};
            var e = this.options("transitions"),
                r = !!e,
                n = !!e.transforms,
                o = !!e.transforms3d,
                a = s.duration || 0,
                l = this.list();
            if (!r && a > 0) return l.animate(i, s), void 0;
            var h = s.complete || t.noop,
                u = {};
            if (r) {
                var c = l.css(["transitionDuration",
                        "transitionTimingFunction",
                        "transitionProperty"
                    ]),
                    f = h;
                h = function() {
                    t(this).css(c), f.call(this)
                }, u = {
                    transitionDuration: (a > 0 ? a / 1e3 : 0) +
                        "s",
                    transitionTimingFunction: e.easing || s.easing,
                    transitionProperty: a > 0 ? function() {
                        return n || o ? "all" : i.left ?
                            "left" : "top"
                    }() : "none",
                    transform: "none"
                }
            }
            o ? u.transform = "translate3d(" + (i.left || 0) + "," +
                (i.top || 0) + ",0)" : n ? u.transform =
                "translate(" + (i.left || 0) + "," + (i.top || 0) +
                ")" : t.extend(u, i), r && a > 0 && l.one(
                    "transitionend webkitTransitionEnd oTransitionEnd otransitionend MSTransitionEnd",
                    h), l.css(u), 0 >= a && l.each(function() {
                    h.call(this)
                })
        },
        _scroll: function(i, e, r) {
            if (this.animating) return t.isFunction(r) && r.call(
                this, !1), this;
            if ("object" != typeof i ? i = this.items().eq(i) : i.jquery ===
                void 0 && (i = t(i)), 0 === i.size()) return t.isFunction(
                r) && r.call(this, !1), this;
            this.inTail = !1, this._prepare(i);
            var n = this._position(i),
                o = s(this.list().position()[this.lt]);
            if (n === o) return t.isFunction(r) && r.call(this, !1),
                this;
            var a = {};
            return a[this.lt] = n + "px", this._animate(a, e, r),
                this
        },
        _scrollTail: function(i, s) {
            if (this.animating || !this.tail) return t.isFunction(s) &&
                s.call(this, !1), this;
            var e = this.list().position()[this.lt];
            this.rtl ? e += this.tail : e -= this.tail, this.inTail = !
                0;
            var r = {};
            return r[this.lt] = e + "px", this._update({
                target: this._target.next(),
                fullyvisible: this._fullyvisible.slice(1).add(
                    this._visible.last())
            }), this._animate(r, i, s), this
        },
        _animate: function(i, s, e) {
            if (e = e || t.noop, !1 === this._trigger("animate"))
                return e.call(this, !1), this;
            this.animating = !0;
            var r = this.options("animation"),
                n = t.proxy(function() {
                    this.animating = !1;
                    var t = this.list().find(
                        "[data-jcarousel-clone]");
                    t.size() > 0 && (t.remove(), this._reload()),
                        this._trigger("animateend"), e.call(
                            this, !0)
                }, this),
                o = "object" == typeof r ? t.extend({}, r) : {
                    duration: r
                },
                a = o.complete || t.noop;
            return s === !1 ? o.duration = 0 : t.fx.speeds[o.duration] !==
                void 0 && (o.duration = t.fx.speeds[o.duration]), o
                .complete = function() {
                    n(), a.call(this)
                }, this.move(i, o), this
        },
        _prepare: function(i) {
            var e, r, n, o = this.index(i),
                a = o,
                l = this.dimension(i),
                h = this.clipping(),
                u = this.vertical ? "bottom" : this.rtl ? "left" :
                "right",
                c = this.options("center"),
                f = {
                    target: i,
                    first: i,
                    last: i,
                    visible: i,
                    fullyvisible: h >= l ? i : t()
                };
            if (c && (l /= 2, h /= 2), h > l)
                for (;;) {
                    if (e = this.items().eq(++a), 0 === e.size()) {
                        if (!this.circular) break;
                        if (e = this.items().eq(0), r = this._visible
                            .index(e) >= 0, i.get(0) === e.get(0))
                            break;
                        if (r && e.after(e.clone(!0).attr(
                                "data-jcarousel-clone", !0)), this.list()
                            .append(e), !r) {
                            var d = {};
                            d[this.lt] = this.dimension(e) * (this.rtl ?
                                -1 : 1), this.moveBy(d)
                        }
                        this._items = null
                    }
                    if (l += this.dimension(e), f.last = e, f.visible =
                        f.visible.add(e), n = s(e.css("margin-" + u)),
                        h >= l - n && (f.fullyvisible = f.fullyvisible
                            .add(e)), l >= h) break
                }
            if (!this.circular && !c && h > l)
                for (a = o;;) {
                    if (0 > --a) break;
                    if (e = this.items().eq(a), 0 === e.size())
                        break;
                    if (l += this.dimension(e), f.first = e, f.visible =
                        f.visible.add(e), n = s(e.css("margin-" + u)),
                        h >= l - n && (f.fullyvisible = f.fullyvisible
                            .add(e)), l >= h) break
                }
            return this._update(f), this.tail = 0, c || "circular" ===
                this.options("wrap") || "custom" === this.options(
                    "wrap") || this.index(f.last) !== this.items().size() -
                1 || (l -= s(f.last.css("margin-" + u)), l > h && (
                    this.tail = l - h)), this
        },
        _position: function(t) {
            var i = this._first,
                s = i.position()[this.lt],
                e = this.options("center"),
                r = e ? this.clipping() / 2 - this.dimension(i) / 2 :
                0;
            return this.rtl && !this.vertical ? (s -= this.clipping() -
                    this.dimension(i), s += r) : s -= r, !e && (
                    this.index(t) > this.index(i) || this.inTail) &&
                this.tail ? (s = this.rtl ? s - this.tail : s +
                    this.tail, this.inTail = !0) : this.inTail = !1, -
                s
        },
        _update: function(i) {
            var s, e = this,
                r = {
                    target: this._target || t(),
                    first: this._first || t(),
                    last: this._last || t(),
                    visible: this._visible || t(),
                    fullyvisible: this._fullyvisible || t()
                },
                n = this.index(i.first || r.first) < this.index(r.first),
                o = function(s) {
                    var o = [],
                        a = [];
                    i[s].each(function() {
                            0 > r[s].index(this) && o.push(this)
                        }), r[s].each(function() {
                            0 > i[s].index(this) && a.push(this)
                        }), n ? o = o.reverse() : a = a.reverse(),
                        e._trigger("item" + s + "in", t(o)), e._trigger(
                            "item" + s + "out", t(a)), e["_" + s] =
                        i[s]
                };
            for (s in i) o(s);
            return this
        }
    })
}
```

Hope you can help.

I have updated my include scripts but it is still not working.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/ui/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/add2cart-go2cart/common.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/theme/madame/js/common.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/theme/madame/js/jquery.flexslider.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/theme/madame/js/fancybox/jquery.fancybox-1.3.4.pack.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/theme/madame/js/fancybox/fancybox.setting.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/theme/madame/js/jquery.accordion.source.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/theme/madame/js/jquery.tweet.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/theme/madame/js/bootstrap/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="instafeed.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/theme/madame/js/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/nivo-slider/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js"></script>
```

This is the error I am getting in console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'animate' on 'Element': 1 argument required, but only 0 present. ilovefancydress.com/catalog/view/javascript/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js:3

Comment: Your *link to JS file* is completely useless at least for two reasons - the main is that the JS code is minified therefore completely unreadable and instead of pointing to a file on your server you should be pointing to the plugin's homepage while mentioning the version you are using. Also I doubt anybody here would search and debug the plugin's code. It would also help (everybody, but you the most!) if you try to search before, since putting the error `Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined` into google would give you thousands of results similar to your problem with **solutions**.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your target page it appears you are loading your carousel before you have loaded your jquery:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/theme/madame/js/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
```

If you are loading any *jQuery-dependant* plugins they have to be loaded after the *jQuery* itself is loaded. Sometimes jQuery plugins depend also on jQuery UI, therefore they need to be loaded after this one as well. In Your case the correct solution should be:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/javascript/jquery/ui/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="catalog/view/theme/madame/js/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>
```

Make sure there are no other dependencies and if they are make sure to fullfill them.

Comment: I have updated my include scripts but it is still not working.

Cheers, Luke

Comment: Looks like you console errors are gone. I have not used that plug in but I would assume you are not initializing it properly. I found this jsfiddle that has it working, look at how it is initialized there: http://jsfiddle.net/Znztg/

Comment: @Speedy Though this is pointing to the right place, it is not a very good answer, since unexperienced user may not be any wiser after all. It is always better after pointing to the problem to write also the correct solution as I did after editing you answer. Feel free to improve it.